# Checking pattern as much as possible

Tags: php, regex

How to make preg find all possible solutions for regular expression pattern?

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$text = 'Amazing analyzing.';
$regexp = '/(^|\\b)([\\S]*)(a)([\\S]*)(\\b|$)/ui';
$matches = array();

if (preg_match_all($regexp, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        echo "{$match[2]}[{$match[3]}]{$match[4]}\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Output:

```
Am[a]zing
an[a]lyzing.
```

Output that i need:

```
[A]mazing
Am[a]zing
[A]nalyzing.
an[a]lyzing.
```

Comment: read about non-greedy matching

Comment: You can't get the result as you expected because one match is included in another. Use lookahead and lookbehind assertions but in php , look-behind won't allow quantifiers inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use look behind/ahead zero-length assertions (instead of a normal pattern which consumes the characters around what your are looking for): http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Lookaround assertions won't help, for two reasons:

- Since they are zero-length, they won't return characters that you need.
- As Avinash Raj noted, PHP lookbehind doesn't allow `*`.

This yields the output that you need:

```
<?php

$text = 'Amazing analyzing.';

foreach (preg_split('/\s+/', $text) as $word)
{
    $matches = preg_split('/(a)/i', $word, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    for ($match = 1; $match < count($matches); $match += 2)
    {
        $prefix = join(array_slice($matches, 0, $match));
        $suffix = join(array_slice($matches, $match+1));
        echo "{$prefix}[{$matches[$match]}]{$suffix}\n";
    }
}

?>
```